# Better way to call a private method

Tags: coffeescript

I'm using CoffeeScript to create a class and build a private method, but my code feels kludgy.

As in the example below, first I define the method with = and then I am forced to use the call method on the portion to be used. But this seems like a kludgy workaround, so I want to know if there is a cleaner solution.

```
class Human
  constructor: (@name, @height, @weight) ->

  _realWeight = ->
    @weight

  answerWeight: ->
    console.log(_realWeight.call(@) - 5)

$ ->
  ken = new Human('Ken', 165, 70)
  ken.answerWeight()
```

Comment: There are no private properties in JavaScript so there aren't any in CoffeeScript either. What you really have is a *function* that is defined within the scope of the `Human` function. Using `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply` is about all you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

No.

## Longer Answer

There is only one way to have truly private data in javascript/coffeescript: closures.

First, lets consider some alternatives:

**Symbols**

Because symbols are unique they can be used to create psuedo-private data:
you can only access the property if you have a reference to the symbol its keyed to:

```
foo = Symbol('I am unique')
bar = {}
bar[foo] = "I am almost private"
```

Code that doesn't have access to `foo` can't easily get to that property of `bar` except for `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`. So not easy to break, but breakable.

**Underscores**

Typical naming convention says that properties/methods prefixed or followed by an underscore are 'private', they are not to be used by an external caller. However, that 'privacy' is not in any way enforced by the runtime.

So lets talk about closures.

**Simple Closure example**

```
makeFoo = (something) -> getSomething: -> something
foo = makeFoo(3)
foo.something      # undefined
foo.getSomething() # 3
```

Now there is no way to get at the parameter passed to the constructor except to call the method. This pattern, while slightly more elegant in coffeescript, is still kinda lame. Lots of duplicated function objects. Not so bad for just `getSomething`, but add a bunch of methods and it gets ugly fast. Also, typically not as easily optimized by the JIT compiler as `foo = new Foo()` would be. Fortunately, ES 2015 to the rescue:

**Advanced Closure Example**

```
Foo = null
do ->
  privateData = new WeakMap()
  getSomething = -> privateData.get(this)
  Foo = class Foo
    constructor: (something) -> privateData.set(this, something)
    getSomething: getSomething


foo = new Foo(3)
foo.something              # undefined
foo.getSomething()         # 3
new Foo(42).getSomething() # 42
foo instanceof Foo         # true
```

Now all instances of `Foo` share one copy of `getSomething` rather than each getting their own. The weakmap is hidden in the closure created by the IIFE, and because of the 'weak' part of `WeakMap` when the instance gets garbage collected the private data will be as well. You are also now potentially able to enjoy the benefits of the compiler optimizing `new`ly created objects. Last but not least, `instanceof` still works properly (to the extent that it ever works properly).

[Further reading.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

[Even More reading](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/53/)

## Note

`WeakMaps` are not supported in all browsers (for IE its 11 or bust). There is a shim, but it cannot be completely polyfilled. Whether or not the shim gets close enough is a call you'll have to make.